# 'Moving window' based on partions. Use partions in SQL Sever or SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssas

Here's the situation. ..  We have a log/audit table within our health-care system. Nearly every action (opening a window, close window, data entry, data change and so on) is registered in this table.

That means that there are millions and millions of records in that log/audit table. That is not really a problem, that's a fact I have to deal with.

Now we want to make a PowerBI dashboard which shows 2 weeks (14 days) of data. This 14-day window 'moves' over time. When we hit day 15, the data of day 1 is no longer needed.

Here's the question:
Do I use partions in SQL Server? Or do I use partions in SSAS-tabular model? Or do I use them both?

Which way to go?

Any answer, hint, tip, reference is welcome.

Comment: Or none. Just use a `WHERE created>DATEADD(ww,-2,getdate())` clause in your `SELECT` that read newer data and if you *really* need to delete the old data, execute a `DELETE` periodically with a `WHERE created>DATEADD(ww,-2,getdate())` that deletes the old data. Partitions would only help if you had millions of records per week and wanted to quickly discard the data. They wouldn't improve speed at all

Comment: This doesn't seem directly related to partitions. I'd just set up your query in Power BI just to pull the last 14 days of data.

Comment: If the date field is covered by an index, filtering will be fast. If the table has proper indexes, if it uses a columnstore index, aggregations will also be fast.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we have millions of records each day, so my thought was to create a partition for each day, fill it with data of that day and then pass it to the SSAS model. If I have a query that uses dateadd(ww, -x, getdate()) << where x between 1 and 15 >> the number of record will increase.

Comment: The number of records will remain the same, partition or not. Partitions don't affect query results or performance (they actually degrade it because the server has to scan multiple partitions). They only help with data management, ie moving and deleting. You'll have to write the proper `WHERE` statement if you want to retrieve only 15 days of data.

Comment: Partitions *don't* affect parallelisation of a query. The server will generate a parallelized execution plan if the cost is high enough anyway. Parallelized operations don't go reading from multiple disk files either - that can *reduce* performance too, as there's only so much bandwidth. They filter, aggregate and process the in-memory data as it comes from disks, and merge it back to produce the output.

Comment: If you have a current SQL Server version (2016 and later) you can use columnstore indexes to speed up analytic queries immensely *and* achieve data compression too. For a columnstore index 1M rows is "just" a single delta (uncompressed batch) so having multiple millions of rows per day is no concern. The catchy name for this is [real time operational analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/get-started-with-columnstore-for-real-time-operational-analytics?view=sql-server-ver15)